# Hot to get serialized String from ConsumerRecord?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I try to use Kafka with JSON as format for the value. To handle the deserialization in my consumer automatically and also to have a logging I set it up for JsonDeserializer and an custom ErrorHandler.

**application.properties**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer = org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class = org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
```

**KafkaConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig 
{
    @Bean
    public DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler (KafkaTemplate <String, String> template) 
    {
        return new DefaultErrorHandler ()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleRemaining (Exception ex, java.util.List<ConsumerRecord <?, ?>> records,
            Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) 
            {
              // here we do logging stuff
              System.out.println ("##: " + records.size ());
              System.out.println ("ex: " + ex.getMessage());
              ConsumerRecord <?, ?> cr = records.get (0);
              System.out.println ("ku: " + KafkaUtils.format (cr));
              System.out.println ("st: " + cr.toString ());
              System.out.println ("key: " + cr.key ());
              System.out.println ("val: " + cr.value ());
              System.out.println ("vsz: "+ cr.serializedValueSize());
            }
        };
    }
```

So far, so good - all is working.

Now I think of a way to the the value as a string to have it in my logging.

How can I get that out of ConsumerRecord?

Output so far is this in case of a wrong message. I simply test with kafka-producer.sh script that is part of kafka and let me send messages by the console. vsz matches my input - so can not be completely wrong.

```
##: 1
ex: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided
ku: mytopic-0@82
st: ConsumerRecord(topic = mytopic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 82, CreateTime = 1650039248945, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 3, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = springDeserializerExceptionValue, value = [-84, -19,..., 112, 1 100, 102])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = null)
key: null
val: null
vsz: 3
```

My idea is to create a StringSerializer - but cr.value () is null - so thats a dead end.

Comment: The deserialization failed, so why are you expecting any non null key or value? You'll have to  at least use a ByteDeserializer to get the actual data. Or, perhaps you should apply a "default type" like the logs say?

Comment: The value that could not be deserialized is available in the `data` property of the `DeserializationException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `super.handleRemaining()` in your overridden method so that the records are properly repositioned for the next poll.

The value that could not be deserialized is available in the `DeserializationException`, which is the cause of the `ListenerExecutionFailedExeption` passed into the error handler.

```java
/**
 * Get the data that failed deserialization (value or key).
 * @return the data.
 */
public byte[] getData() {
    return this.data; // NOSONAR array reference
}
```